# Python: MVC implementation with complex model interaction

Tags: python, macos, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm working on a small python (3.6.4) application (for mac os) and I'm having some trouble with implementing a controller/model relationship. I'm kind of new to python and MVC (and design patterns in general for that matter).

The program creates zip files that can be written to tape. Three folders that are used:

- input_folder - Where the user can copy Project folders to.
- process_folder - Where Projects are copied to and processed by the program.
- output_folder - Contains projects with zip files created by the program.

Basic steps of the program:

1. The program watches the input folder for "Project folders". The Project folders contain one or more "Episode folders" that each have some files in them.
2. The program checks if the name of a project folder is present in a database (user is responsible for adding project names) and creates a matching Project folder in the process folder with a formatted name (lowercase_without_spaces).
3. Episode folders for each episode are also checked. (In this case if they haven't been archived before)
4. Episodes are copied from the input folder to the process folder once the files they contain are complete. (i.e. Filesize stays the same for 3 seconds)
5. For each Project, episodes are zipped from the process folder and moved to the corresponding Project folder in the output folder.

I have a Project and Episode class. Both classes contain their folder name from the input folder and their formatted name upon which the folder names in the process folder are based.

Each Project object contains a list of Episode objects and eventually every Episode object contains a list of File objects. (Probably very bad...)

Currently I have a controller that takes care of both Projects and Episodes within projects so control remains in a central place. For example:

```
project.add_episodes(Episode('sometitle'))
project.process_episodes()
```

A couple of questions:

- Is my single controller approach the correct way to do this?
- What could be a good design pattern for my Project/Episode data model?

Any help/advice would be great!

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague. In this current question, you are asking too may questions. Also, take advantage of markup, makes it easier for others to understand.

Comment: I think this question is better suited on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) as it involves best practices and conventions. (Couldn't find a matching flag, but it is possible for you to request migration of your question)

Comment: @brotherperes I updated my post to correctly display the bullets for each question. I find it very hard chopping this big problem into smaller bite-size pieces. That's why I invite everyone to ask questions if things are unclear. I do understand the need for a brief description of the problem.

Comment: @yarwest How do I do that?

Comment: I'll look for a link when I'm not on mobile, you should be able to find it in help/meta though.

Comment: @W.Deen sorry for the late response but here is some more information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site

Comment: I asked for migration to CS like you suggested @yarwest. Also, I edited my original post. I think it is a lot more specific now.

Comment: @d1che you can always delete your post here and reask it there. As it's got no answers here, a migration isn't much helpful. Be sure to read their FAQ before posting.